How to get r_liteprofile, r_emailaddress, and w_member_social scope in linkedIn Application ? I am getting below error
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "Scope &quot;r_liteprofile&quot; is not authorized for your application",
  "error": "AuthorizationError: Scope &quot;r_liteprofile&quot; is not authorized for your application\n    at LinkedinStrategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:138:25)\n    at attempt (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:378:16)\n    at authenticate (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:379:7)\n    at /Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:88:3\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at /Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:80:83\n    at MixinAuthGuard.canActivate (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:44:32)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)",
  "timestamp": "2024-06-01T00:26:18.661Z",
  "path": "/linkedin/callback error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_liteprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application",
  "method": "GET"
}

I am getting this error while accessing the token for a user to use the linkedIn APis

This question is similar to: Don't have `r_emailaddress` or `r_liteprofile` scopes in linkedIn app API. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
